# R: compare and subset two strings

Tags: r, string, compare

Is there a function in R that can respond at these requirements:

```
if string1 exists in string2 then remove string1 from string2
```

I passed a day searching on a such function. So, any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

I have a dataframe. Here's a part of it:

```
mark      name                                ChekMark
Caudalie  Caudalie Eau démaquillante 200ml    TRUE
Mustela   Mustela Bébé lait hydra corps 300ml TRUE
Lierac    Lierac Phytolastil gel prévention   TRUE
```

I want to create an new dataframe in witch the mark doesn't exist on the product name.

That's my final goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `gsub` and work with regular expressions:

```
gsub(" this part ", " ", "A Text where this part should be removed")
# [1] "A Text where should be removed"
gsub(" this part ", " ", "A Text where this 1 part should be removed")
# [1] "A Text where this 1 part should be removed"
```

Comment: I switched my dataframe to a list and I tried to use `gsub`, but It doesn't work for me: `lst<-lapply(1:length(spl), function(i) 
  {ifelse(spl[[i]]$CheckMark==TRUE,gsub(spl[[i]]$nom_marque,'',spl[[i]]$nom),spl[[i]])})`

Comment: `gsub` and `mapply` resolved the problem :

`df_mod=as.data.frame(mapply(gsub,data_mod$marq,"",data_mod$nom_det))`. Thank you for your time and your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for string2.replace(string1, '')?

or you could:

```
>>> R = lambda string1, string2: string2.replace(string1, '')
>>> R('abc', 'AAAabcBBB')
'AAABBB'
>>>
```

Comment: Yes I'm looking for a something like this. Any idea ?

Comment: `gsub` and `mapply` resolved the problem :

`df_mod=as.data.frame(mapply(gsub,data_mod$marq,"",data_mod$nom_det))`. Thank you for your time and your efforts.